# How to use Catalyst to search, select and display entries from my database

Tags: sqlite, controller, catalyst, dbix-class

I have to use Catalyst in order to create a database and access it through a browser.
I have created a very simple database using DBIx-class and sqlite, just one table and filled it with some records.
I have managed to display the whole table and its rows using Template Toolkit view module and the code below into my controller.

```
$c->stash(ptm => [$c->model('DB::ptm')->all]);
```

Now I have created a simple search box in order to search the database and display any entries that match with the keyword, but I don't know how to pass the keyword to my controller nor how to implement the subroutine in order to achieve this.

I have searched for more than three days without finding any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two completely different problems here.

1. Accepting arguments in Catalyst
2. Performing a search in DBIC

So, starting with the first one. [Reading a query string](http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90042/lib/Catalyst/Request.pm#%24req-%3Equery_params).

```
$c->request->query_parameters->{field}
```

Then performing a search. Just call `search` instead of `all` and pass a hashref of your columns and values.

```
$c->model('DB::ptm')->search( { 'name' => $tag } );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How could I connect the $tag variable with my HTML input search box?

Comment: `my $tag = $c->request->params->{name_of_HTML_input};` The log from your stand-alone server will show you exactly what's being passed back from the browser to your application.